# Extract data after '_' string in Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have table with location data.

```
91026_2854869
91026_1017246
91026_1101125
91026_3453666
```

I want to extract numbers after '_' and display the results like below

```
2854869
1017246
1101125
3453666
```

I tried below query but returns error in datastudio

```
split(location_id,"_")[OFFSET(0)] as location_code
```

I this REGEXP_EXTRACT works well than this.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in standard SQL:

```
with data as (
 select '91026_2854869' as x
 UNION ALL
 select '91026_1017246' as x
 UNION ALL
 select '91026_1101125' as x
 UNION ALL
 select '91026_3453666' as x
)
select REGEXP_EXTRACT(x,  r"_([0-9]+)") from data;
```